# mongoDB find where date is in Array of Date Ranges

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

My documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60841a6047fda45b6391dbce"
    },
    "title": "Week 1",
    "dates": [{
        "start": {
            "$date": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "end": {
            "$date": "2021-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }, {
        "start": {
            "$date": "2021-05-10T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "end": {
            "$date": "2021-05-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }]
}
```

Now I try to find documents where a given date in in one of these ranges. (Expected result is no documents, but this query is returning my document.)

```
{
    $and: [
        {'dates.start': {$lte: ISODate('2021-05-05')}},
        {'dates.end': {$gte: ISODate('2021-05-05')}}
   ]
}
```

How can I query if the start and end date in one object includes my date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria,

```
{
  dates: {
    $elemMatch: {
      start: { $lte: ISODate("2021-05-05") },
      end: { $gte: ISODate("2021-05-05") }
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wxLU5VUYR0J)